# Python websocket server command stream (lua client)?

Tags: python, websocket, lua, minecraft

After seeing a video about a youtuber who uses a websocket server to interacte with an entity in a video game (minecraft) video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwKRbsDbxqc&t=25s&ab_channel=Ottomated

I wanted to recreate the same idea, but with some little tweaks:

- I wanted the websocket server to be host in python
- I wanted to be able to interact without any html or javascript

So I built the websocket server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

async def server(websocket, path):
    data = await websocket.recv()
    
    while True:
        msg = input('type the command: ')
        await websocket.send(msg)



start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

(really simple)

and the client side (in lua):

```
print('connecting')

local ws, err = http.websocket("ws://localhost:8765")

if not ws then
    return printError(err)
    ws.close()
end

ws.send("message")

repeat
    command = ws.receive()  
    load(command)()
until command == "stop"

ws.close()
```

The only thing is that after the first message gets executed by the lua programm, it stops processing the other messages.
I don't  know what I did wrong!

Am I doing it the wrong way? or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

well i am still learning sockets and improving my server-side skill but it is easy you just need to make it a loop 'while true:' or i prefer a controllable variable 'kim = True
while kim :' then you can make false or true to close or open the loop under certian conditions and i think you need somthing like threads to not block the other clients input
well i didnt study web-server but the problem is as i think its that you only receive one message because its not in a loop so it will excute the code and then close

Comment: Yeah, but the loop on the client side isn't working either... but maybe the threads can help

Comment: yea you need that import threading then after putting the code that is goingto get looped in a function then type  'name1' = threading.thread(target = 'function_name' , arg = 'parameters of the function') then type name1.start() you can do several threads like make another function put it in thread then change the 'name1' and start it

Comment: yea it does remove the overloading clients its even used in facbook i saw it when i was looking in their script yea if it dosent work raise some exception and try to know the error and fix hope i helped , wait did you import  the librys in the client side ??

Comment: I imported websocket on the client side (and threading but it doesn't work either), I think i'll really have to put myself to understand a bit better sockets